# How to check if a password is valid and matches a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a function that sometimes will receive a massive calls (near 2k/minute) and it should check if the password is valid.

My requirements are simple:

- At least 5 characters;
- At least 1 number;
- At least 1 uppercase letter;
- At least 1 lowercase letter;
- At least 1 special character.

For now, I have code my function as:

```
import re

def check(p):

    return re.match(r"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{5}$", p)
```

I have some questions:

- Why my regex only works for 5 characters? If I try to validate a string with 6 characters, it fails.
- Isn't regex kinda slow during peak time? What are other alternatives?

Comment: Is you requirement to have 5 characters or at least 5 characters?

Comment: My bad, it should have at least 5 characters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression matching anything greater than eight letters in length, in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604105/regular-expression-matching-anything-greater-than-eight-letters-in-length-in-py)

Comment: To get some speed boost, compile your regex pattern beforehand

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick (note the `{5,}`):

```
re.match(r"(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{5,}$", p)
```

---

In other words, `{5,}` means *5 or more* as opposed to `{5}` that means *exactly 5*.

Comment: You may limit max characters by specifying `{5,18}`

Comment: Note that `(?!.*\s).` can be replaced with `(\S)`

Comment: @placplacboom I didn’t get it.

Comment: @smac89 Right you are. Interestingly, the actual *stated* requirements said nothing about white space not being allowed in a password; they only expressed what must be present but not what cannot be present in a password.